# Orthographic projection in OpenGL

Tags: opengl-es

I'm trying to set an orthographic projection using gl.glOrthof...

However, it doesn't matter which values I pass into the function, the width and height seems to get constant float values and they don't match my glOrthof attributes.

My surfaceChanged code:

```
gl.glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
gl.glOrthof(0.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

My draw code:

```
gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);  
((GL11Ext) gl).glDrawTexfOES(positionX, positionY, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
```

Any ideas? Tell me if you need to know something.

Comment: I need to see a bot more of your code, especially the full drawing function.

Comment: @datenwolf: Added my full draw code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

glDrawTexfOES width and height parameters are in pixels, so instead of

```
((GL11Ext) gl).glDrawTexfOES(positionX, positionY, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
```

you should use

```
((GL11Ext) gl).glDrawTexfOES(positionX, positionY, 0.0f, texture_width, texture_height);
```

The projection and modelview matrix influence only the positioning of the x,y position, not the texture scaling. Selecting the part of the texture to be used is done with the *crop rectangle*.

Comment: Thanks will try this. I'll let you know.